# xrandr does not scale screen as expected

Tags: xorg, display, display-resolution, xrandr, scaling

I tried using xrandr command to lower resolution, run `wine some_game.exe`, then return resolution to normal.
like so:

```
xrandr --size 1024x768 --output DP-0 --scale 1x1
WINEARCH=win32 wine Hoyle_Board_Games.exe
xrandr --size 3840x2160 --output DP-0 --scale 0.66x0.66
```

but it is not behaving as expected.

running the last command makes everything huge. [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/I62ig.png)

but when I run `xrandr --size 3840x2160 --output DP-0 --scale 2x2` everything becomes very tiny.

I have NVidia drivers installed, IDK if this is caused by compounded scaling from NVidia X server settings.

But What I want is that my screen resolution & scaling returns to [default display settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FFK2M.png)